# Executing Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with space between its arguements

Tags: java, runtime, executable

Good day to all experts,

Hope to have some advice on this trivial issue of mine.

I am trying to execute the following syntax while passing the arguments `testcase1`,`testdata1` and `testresult` to `jar_filepath`,`tc`,`test_data` and `test_result` respectively

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k java -jar "+jar_filepath + tc + test_data + test_result);`

However, upon execution, there was an error as follow:
`Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\TestAutomation\Jar\Test1.jartestcase1testdata1testresult2` where all the arguments' space is not applied.

Hope to have advice on the proper way to write the code for execution at the exec() level.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you'd have to include spaces in front of the argument strings. Or pass a `String[]` instead, with each argument as an element.

Comment: Hi Jorn, thank you for your feedback. I believe I did add space in front of the argument strings, as per the syntax Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k java -jar "+jar_filepath + tc + test_data + test_result);

Comment: As for you second suggestion, do you mean that the arguments are first stored in an array, then call it in exec() as an array itself rather that as elements individually ? Really appreciate your advice and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way does *not* add spaces before the arguments. That would look like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd /k java -jar "
    + jar_filepath + " " + tc + " " + test_data + " " + test_result);
```

But if you use a `String[]` this is done automatically:

```
String[] command = {
    "cmd /c start",
    "cmd /k java -jar " + jar_filepath,
    tc,
    test_data,
    test_result
};

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comand);
```

Comment: How could I miss that .......thanks a lot for waking me up !!! Thumbs up to you, Jorn !